# How to let Google read but don't display results from page

Tags: google

If I have a page which I want to allow Google to crawl to find links but not display in search results, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you serve that page with a meta tag, which says "noindex, follow":

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" />
```

This means for google what you've been searching for.

Answer (score 0):

3 ways come to mind.

1. If you use google webmaster tools you could go through that interface and ask google to remove the index from pages it has already indexed.
2. You could modify your robots.txt file to disallow google from accessing specific pages on your site.
3. If you want google not to index certain sections of your site then you would use the google appliance googleoff googleon tags in your html.
   http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewC8614968-56ED-4729-9C12-F01677DAC412.htm.

They work with google's spider in addition to google's hardware search appliance that not many people own.

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your answer but that is not what I am asking. I want Google to read the page but not display it in search results.

Comment: `googleoff` and `googleon` **DO NOT WORK** with Googlebot for web search: [Can you use googleon and googleoff comments to prevent Googlebot from indexing part of a page?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/can-you-use-googleon-and-googleoff-comments-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-p)