# Preventing some parts of the pages of a site from being indexed

Tags: google, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, google-index, noindex

My website has links like:

```
<a href="messages.aspx">Messages<span>3</span></a>
```

Well google indexes these links as:  Messages3

I have read some articles for preventing google from indexing some parts of the website like

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
<!--googleon: index>
```

tags but there are 2 problems:

1.This seems very odd to use lots of these tags and for a number

```
    <!--googleoff: index-->
      0
    <!--googleon: index>
```

2.I want to know is there a way or a rule that would work for all search engines like bing and yahoo too.

Comment: [googleoff and googleon only works on Google Search Appliance](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/can-you-use-googleon-and-googleoff-comments-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-p), not normal search results, and for bing/yahoo nothing exists. You should also be aware that display results for users and different elements for search engines is a form of cloaking, which is obviously not permitted. You should tread carefully. It is however ok to hide content with authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use robots.txt. It works for all search engines.

As the content concerned:

Sometimes, there's a certain piece of content on a webpage (or a persistent piece of content throughout a site) that you'd prefer search engines didn't see. In this event, clever use of iframes can come in handy. The HTML Inline Frame Element () represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page.

For better understanding, here's the picture.

[image]

Comment: well, you didn't read the question well. I don't want to prevent a page from being indexed. I just want to leave some words, and numbers out.

Comment: aaa, sorry, I misunderstood. I'll add some edits (i'm using iframes for content), I'll write you down in a minute.

Comment: iframe works for all search engines too :)

Comment: So, is this what you're searching for?