# Registered address different to a businesses operating location

Tags: local-seo, google-local-search

In the UK a company is required by [law to state their registered address on their website](https://www.gov.uk/running-a-limited-company/signs-stationery-and-promotional-material). It is common here for a company to use their accountant's address as their registered address. This can be many miles from where the actual business is run from.

For example, the registered office could be in **Manchester**, but the company is actually based in **London**, and sells to the London area.

How can I display the registered address of a company, and not confuse/harm that company's local search standing.

Answer (score 1):

As with any other SEO, it will be about making sure the most signals point to the right address, so when they have to decide between the two, they are more likely to choose the one with the strongest signals.  With your location, I'd imagine adding your business to [Google My Business](https://support.google.com/business) will carry far more weight than text they find on the page, especially if you list both addresses on your site.

If you are really worried, you could always add the address to another site and embed it with an iframe for your users so that it does not technically appear on your site.  However, that would seem over-cautious to me.

Other ways you could increase signals (as always with SEO, only Google know what signals they actually use, and they will change):

- Put the registered address in googleoff tags
- Put the address you want to list in `<adress>` tags, but leave the registered one with non-semantic tags.
- Add the registered address with javascript, or some less-crawlable method.
- Add geotags pointing to the address you want
- The law is unclear, but if it only has to appear on one page of a website, set that page as noindex and nofollow - something like the terms page is unlikely to get you much SEO benefit anyway.  Add the main address to other, crawlable, pages.

Comment: Note https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54736/23812 - `googleon` and `googleoff` are only supported by the Google Search Appliance, not Google's web-search.

Answer (score 1):

It's no problem Google Local supports businesses with multiple physical addresses, simply [add both locations](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3217744?hl=en) to your account. This will ensure Google has the correct information about your business, its common for businesses to have HQ, HR and SHOP outlets in their locations, just look at Tesco as a prime example.