# Restrict google from indexingcertain content on my page

Tags: seo, google, yandex

I have an ecommerce shop with ~10 000 items.

I wrote parser to load this items to my website from another website.
But items description is not unique. So I am afraid that google can bun my website.

So I have question how can I prevent google from indexing certain parts of my website? I will rewrite the description later but it will take to much time.

So i found this question https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/webmasters/Z5JP3UQCVWg

And I can see 3 solutions.

1. Create an Iframe where I can load description. And use meta noindex tag.
2. Load content with js ( I read this at the link provided).
   So tell me more about it? 
   Does content loaded with js from external file being not indexed by Google?
   (I mean I have div and if write something like `$(div).html('not indexed content')` will it work?
3. I found this link just now [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

So basically it says I should have a `div style =" display:none"`
And then I should remove this `display:none` with js. This seems to be the easiest way to do it.
Does it really work?
Will it be working not in google but in other search engines(I am worried only about `yandex.ru` actuaaly)

Comment: Google understands content in JS... so that won't work. Google on/off won't work either `"googleon" and "googleoff" are only supported by the Google Search Appliance (when you host your own search results, usually for your own internal website).`. See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/can-you-use-googleon-and-googleoff-comments-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-p Additionally, its common for shops do use manufactuer product details... these are all duplicate... the likes of Amazon, eBay and all other massive online shops use duplicate descriptions without issue...

Comment: The last part of what @SimonHayter is very important. Duplicate product descriptions are not necessarily a problem to be solved. This is very common. Duplicate content, if that is what you are thinking, requires a bit more. As well, search engines understand that e-commerce sites are different and must follow different rules. Just make sure you are building out the rest of the page well and do not worry about it. Cheers!!

Comment: I almost edited the question to make it sound better, but I don't fully understand it since there are numerous questions. To me it seems like the OP wants to not index certain content for some search engines? but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Mike It sounds like the OP is concerned that the product descriptions would be considered duplicate content and wants Google to ignore just the descriptions and not the whole page. Cheers!!

Comment: @Mike I always have this problem actually.I can write a small question but then in comments people will ask for details. Or I can make a detailed description but then again some people will get lost in details. And @ closetnoc is right. I need to ingnore just the descriptions not the whole page. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

In response to your key question point, can Googlebot be restricted from indexing certain portions of a page only the answer is not at this time. The only supported methods at this time for controlling indexing apply to full pages such as adding rel="nofollow" to certain links and using your robots.txt file to deny access to certain resources.

As for what @SimonHayter says it is very common with e-commerce sites for product descriptions to be the same due to the fact that many e-commerce sites take the product descriptions from the manufacturer and so many sites can have duplicated content for the product description. Usually these are only one or two paragraphs in size and so not a big deal as long as the rest of your site is unique. The Googlebot is intelligent enough to identify e-commererce pages based on content and be more forgiving to product descriptions being duplicate content.

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that Google recognises and forgives duplicate product descriptions. There's a recent talk from BrightonSEO highlighting how a leading bookseller lost positions to publishers as a result of using their standard synopses: http://www.slideshare.net/jonathanearnshaw/how-to-fix-any-seo-problem-brighton-seo-april-2016-pi-datametrics (slide 16 onwards).