# Prevent Google from seeing "svg" as a content keyword without using .htaccess

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, google-index, xml, svg

Is there a simple way to do this without using "X-Robots-Tag: noarchive" and robots.txt ? Because in some shared hosting packages it is not possible to modify this kind of values.

I have came across with an alternative solution:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

This one also seems like not valid for svg files.

Problem:

[image]

Comment: It looks like those are **NOT** SVG images that are getting indexed.  Those are directories containing SVG images.     You likely have "directory indexes" turned on.   Turning off that feature will solve your problem.

Comment: And on a host that doesn't permit .htaccess then you won't be able to turn "directory indexes" off - which falls back to Simon's answer - on a severely limited host you don't have a lot of options.

Comment: @w3dk You can disable directory indexes by uploading an index.html file to each directory.   I've put that into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is **not** that SVG images are getting indexed.  The items in your screenshot are image *directories*.   If you visit those URLs you will likely see a list of files that are in the directories. Since they are image directories, the generated index page uses the word "svg".

This is a feature of web servers called "directory index".   If you have *.htaccess* you can turn that off:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Otherwise, you can upload an *index.html* file into each of those directories.    The *index.html* file will take the place of the automatically generated directory listing.    You could make the *index.html* file meta refresh to the home page, and put a `noindex` directive in it for good measure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</head></html>
```

I also want to point out that svg as a content keyword is not a problem that *has* to be fixed.   Google shows the content keywords report so that you can check for spam.   If you saw "viagra" or "escorts" on that list you would know your site has been hacked with unsavory content injected onto it.

As long as the keywords in the content keyword report are not spammy, you don't have to take any action because of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to [noindex htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356266/x-robots-noindex-specific-page-in-htaccess), [noindex robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) or [PHP X-Robots-Tag](https://yoast.com/x-robots-tag-play/) then sadly you don't have a lot of options. Only [Google Search Appliance](https://www.google.com/work/search/products/gsa.html) supports the use of googleoff and googleon.

Unless your interested in GSA the below method won't work, your only option is to **ditch the current hosting** and go with any **decent hosting** provider that will provide you with the necessary features and functions, that Google and Bing expect webmasters to have access to.

> [Excluding Unwanted Text from the Index](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/preparing.html#1076243)
>
> There may be Web pages that you want to suppress from search results
>   when users search on certain words or phrases. For example, if a Web
>   page consists of the text “the user conference page will be completed
>   as soon as Jim returns from medical leave,” you might not want this
>   page to appear in the results of a search on the terms “user
>   conference.”
>
> You can prevent this content from being indexed by using
>   googleoff/googleon tags. By embedding googleon/googleoff tags with
>   their flags in HTML documents, you can disable:
>
> - The indexing of a word or portion of a Web page
> - The indexing of anchor text
> - The use of text to create a snippet in search results

*Example of googleoff*

```
<!--googleoff: index-->

<h2>Inline SVG No Index</h2>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-52 -53 100 100" stroke-width="2">
 <g fill="none">
  <ellipse stroke="#66899a" rx="6" ry="44"/>
  <ellipse stroke="#e1d85d" rx="6" ry="44" transform="rotate(-66)"/>
  <ellipse stroke="#80a3cf" rx="6" ry="44" transform="rotate(66)"/>
  <circle  stroke="#4b541f" r="44"/>
 </g>
 <g fill="#66899a" stroke="white">
  <circle fill="#80a3cf" r="13"/>
  <circle cy="-44" r="9"/>
  <circle cx="-40" cy="18" r="9"/>
  <circle cx="40" cy="18" r="9"/>
 </g>
</svg>
<h2>External SVG No Index</h2>
<img src="example.svg" alt="example">

<!--googleon: index>
```

Comment: googleoff and googleon are only available for the Google search appliance.   Googlebot ignores them completely for web search: [Can you use googleon and googleoff comments to prevent Googlebot from indexing part of a page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/can-you-use-googleon-and-googleoff-comments-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-p)

Comment: Yep, I did put that in but afterwards.