# Prevent search engines from indexing the text in the sidebar that isn't related to the main content but still allow them to follow the links there

Tags: seo, links

I am developing a CMS in PHP. I have a sidebar on most pages and also some other widgets. For example "read other articles" or a list of categories. Google does index that random-like content as part of the page.

In detail: I have a category for network stuff and a category for programming stuff. Sometimes on a page about networking there is a link in the sidebar to an article about programming. I want search engines, to follow those links but NOT index them as part of the page with the promary content about networking! For example I might write about LDAP but in the sidebar there is something about MBA.  When I search Google looking for samba I might find that page.

When I use `rel=nofollow`, as far as I understand they will not follow those links at all.

So how can I define that some content is not to be indexed as part of a specific URL?

The only possible solution I found so far is

```
<!--BeginNoIndex-->
<!--EndNoIndex-->
```

It seems that this tells search engines not to associate content inside those tags with the main page content.

Comment: To confirm, you have source pages linking to the target page with the keyword of the target page, and the source is outranking the target for the keyword?

Comment: yes but not only keywords, every content. when i search for samba i get a search result for the page about ldap. like in the screenshot imagine i search for samba and get directed to the page in the screenshot. but the samba article was just in the sidebar. the exact page is here https://simplepress.ml/?type=post&id=269. there is some random staff on the right side. this i want (not only the link - also the meaning of the word) not to get in relation with this page. but i want google to find the page abaut(ex samba) at its usual place in the category, so i think rel=nofollow is no solution.

Comment: Related: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

Comment: The `BeginNoIndex` and `EndNoIndex` are not supported by Google.  Those are for a search engine called dtSearch by SiteCore.  https://support.dtsearch.com/dts0185.htm    Similarly [Googlebot doesn't support `GoogleOn` and `GoogleOff`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/can-you-use-googleon-and-googleoff-comments-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-p) like some people think.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing is not about pieces of content of a web page, but about the entire web page.

As the correct way to treat the issue, you need to wrap the content inside the sidebar in `<aside></aside>` HTML5 semantic tag which indicates the piece of content inside a web page which isn't directly related to the `<main></main>` content.

The main part of page needs to be wrapped inside `<main>` HTML tag.
The main text of `<main>` content needs to be in a nested `<article>` tag.
The **related but not the main** contents need to be wrapped in `<aside>` tag, nested in `<main>` tag, outside the `<article>` tag.