# Is there something like anti-seo techniques? To NOT be found by certain keywords?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-index, noindex

I wonder if there is something like anti-seo techniques, enabling me to make a website less findable for certain keywords?

For example:
I manage a massage website. This website is purely for massages at home. There are no happy ending or such. It's purely for professional sports- and relaxing massages.

We also explain this about the services on the website. But as many search for xxx services, we still get weekly requests about it. When googling these type of service, we can also find our massage website on the first page of search results, in between escort services websites.

The part where we talk about not providing such services is inside a `div` with `data-nosnippit` attribute, between `googleoff: index` comments.

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
  <div data-nosnippet>
    Our text about NOT providing these services is in here...
  </div>
<!--googleon: index>
```

How can we avoid to be in search results for these kind of adult services?
Is there something like anti-keywords we can use?

This question (or similar) has probably been asked before, but I could not find it.

Comment: Quick note: `googleoff: index` directives are not for use with google search, they are a feature of an enterprise tool called Google Search Appliance. More info [Can you use googleon and googleoff comments to prevent Googlebot from indexing part of a page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/can-you-use-googleon-and-googleoff-comments-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-p)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insight @MaximillianLaumeister.